# Is there a way to offset / limit and count Pilosa query results?

Tags: pilosa

I am doing queries like:

```
response = client.query(
    index.intersect(
        category.row(1),
        location.row(1),
    )
)
result = response.result
columns = result.row.columns
```

And as I have a lot of columns, I can sometimes get millions of results, i.e.

```
len(result.row.columns) > 1000000
```

I can't find a way to apply an offset+limit to the results or count them on the pilosa side and it seems quite inefficient to transfer the whole bulk of results into python and process it there.

Answer (score 3):

Pilosa has a `Count` query, used in the python client like this:

```py
response = client.query(
    index.count(
        index.intersect(
            field1.row(0), 
            field2.row(0),
        )
    )
)
result = response.result
column_count = result.count
```

This corresponds to a PQL query like `Count(Intersect(Row(field1=0), Row(field2=0)))`.

There is not yet a general way to handle offset+limit for row results. One option that may work for you is to handle the results per-shard, by passing a second argument like `shards=[0, 1]` to the query function. Limiting the results to a single shard will produce a result set of no more than `ShardWidth` values (default 2<sup>20</sup> = 1,048,576).

This corresponds to an HTTP request like `curl localhost:10101/index/index1/query?shards=0,1 -d "Intersect(Row(field1=0), Row(field2=0))"`

The [relevant section](https://github.com/pilosa/python-pilosa/blob/master/docs/server-interaction.md#pilosa-client) of the python client docs would benefit from solid examples and further explanation.